# Monthly Calendar || Month View

Tags: children, calendar, parents

So I have `/calendar` and linking previous/next months on that template. The previous/next month urls are `/calendar/2015-08` and `/calendar/2015-08`.

I have this custom route setup:

[image]

On my `/calendar/2015-08` I'm getting this:

`Variable "entry" does not exist`

Part of my template looks like:

```
{% extends '_inc/_layout' %}

{% block meta %}
<title>{% if entry.metaTitle|length %}{{ entry.metaTitle }}{% else %}{{ entry.title }}{% endif %}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ entry.metaDescription }}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ entry.metaKeywords }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

I know why this happening but my question is how do I circumvent this? I want some of the same data on `/calendar` to be on subsequent monthly calendar pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `entry` refer to in this case? Is */calendar* the Entry URL for an entry, and is that the entry you need to access on the other pages?

Comment: `/calendar` works since it's a structure entry. so yes need that data passed down to other calendar pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft won't set the `entry` variable automatically unless the route matches a particular entry. If you're sharing a template between routes that may or may not correspond to an entry, you need to make sure that var gets set explicitly by you if not automatically by Craft:

```
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myStructure').slug('calendar').first %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does't like that `Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected)`

Comment: The `?:` is backwards: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

Comment: hmm now getting `Variable "entry" does not exist. but the parent `/calendar` is working`

Comment: @Mark I edited the example to include `is not defined`. And it was getting a little long for a ternary, so I converted it to a traditional `if` statement.

Comment: that did it! thx again

Comment: That's what I get for trying to be too terse. Thanks, @LindseyD!